# Confusing F# compiler message

Tags: f#, unit-type

The following snippet illustrates the error I'm getting.  Even though both match branches return the same thing; I get error, "This expression was expected to have type unit but here has type 'a -> unit"  I have no clue what the compiler wants here...

```ml
open System.IO 

let FileContent contents =  
  match contents with  
  | "" -> None  
  | c -> Some(c)  

let WriteSomething (contents:string) =  
  let writer = new StreamWriter("")  
  writer.Write( contents ) |> ignore  

let DoStuffWithFileContents =  
  let reader = new StreamReader( "" )  
  let stuff = reader.ReadToEnd()  
  match stuff |> FileContent with  
  | Some(c) -> WriteSomething c  
               |> ignore  
  | None -> ignore  // <- error on "ignore"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`ignore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340357.aspx) operator is actually a function that takes a single input and returns the [`unit` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483472.aspx) (F#'s equivalent of `void`). So when you have `-> ignore` you're returning the `ignore` function.

Instead, use `()` to represent the value of the `unit` type:

```
  | Some(c) -> WriteSomething c  
               |> ignore  
  | None -> ()
```

But actually, since [`StreamWriter.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce2kyyb4.aspx) returns `void`, all these `ignore`'s are unnecessary. You could just as easily write this as:

```
let WriteSomething (contents:string) =  
  let writer = new StreamWriter("")  
  writer.Write(contents)   

let DoStuffWithFileContents =  
  let reader = new StreamReader("")  
  let stuff = reader.ReadToEnd()  
  match stuff |> FileContent with  
  | Some(c) -> WriteSomething c  
  | None -> ()
```

Or even better, use [`Option.iter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340387.aspx):

```
let WriteSomething (contents:string) =  
  let writer = new StreamWriter("")  
  writer.Write(contents)

let DoStuffWithFileContents =  
  let reader = new StreamReader("")  
  let stuff = reader.ReadToEnd()  
  stuff |> FileContent |> Option.iter(WriteSomething)
```

Answer (score 1):

By returning `ignore` on your last line you are returning a function, not a simple value.

The point of `ignore` is to convert things to `()`. Your last line can simply return `()` directly.